# Best way to build application triggering reminder at certain time

Tags: python, web-applications, architecture

I want to build a python app sending reminder at certain time. It would have several subscribers. Each subscriber sets specific moment when they want to be notified. For example, John wants to have a reminder every days whereas Cassandra wants it every months.

I see several ways to do it :

- Use a script running 24/7 with a while loop and checks if it's time to do send the reminder.
- Use a cron tab that runs the script every minutes to check if there's reminder to send
- Create a simple api (in Flask for example). It checks every minutes or so if there is a reminder to send to subscribers or even make a request to the api.

What is the best way to build such application in Python for few subscribers (10) and for a larger amount(1000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a small amount of subscribers I would do a script that run all the times, it would continuously check the time and send reminders as needed, you can use `time` and `datetime` modules for that.

For a large amount of subscribers it would be an API that can manage multiple request simultaneously, you can use `Flask` or `Django` or `FastAPI` for that.

For the API how would it work is that subscribers would make `POST` request with all the informational notification ( date, time, what message they want to receive for example ) then the server store those informations in a database like if you are familiar with python `Celery` seem the best one but you have `Airflow` too, it will schedule a reminder to be executed at a certain time.
Then when the reminder is executed it just retrieve the informations from the database, and send it via email for example

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! How would it work with an API. I don't understand how requests would be built depending on subscribers and date

Comment: @Pi-R You welcome, I updated and expanded my answer for the API answer